# How to implement SQL query, max(count(distinct attribute_name))

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to display out the I_PUBLISHER with the highest number of unique author books published, how can I achieved that in an SQL statement?

Scenario:

```
 Publisher A publishes 10 books with 10 unique author
 Publisher B publishes 10 book with that 10 book from same author.

 BOOK_ID, BOOK_TITLE, BOOK_AUTHOR_ID, BOOK_PUBLISHER,

 SQL statement to get the publisher name with largest number of UNIQUE author
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * 
  FROM
(
  SELECT book_publisher, COUNT(DISTINCT book_author_id) author_count
    FROM table1
   GROUP BY book_publisher
   ORDER BY author_count DESC 
)
 WHERE rownum = 1
```

or

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT book_publisher, COUNT(DISTINCT book_author_id) author_count
    FROM table1
   GROUP BY book_publisher
)
SELECT book_publisher
  FROM cte
 WHERE author_count = 
(
  SELECT MAX(author_count) 
    FROM cte
)
```

or with analytical functions

```
SELECT book_publisher, author_count 
  FROM
(
  SELECT book_publisher,
         COUNT(DISTINCT book_author_id) author_count,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT book_author_id) DESC) rank
    FROM table1
   GROUP BY book_publisher
)
 WHERE rank = 1
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/93e423/23)** demo

Comment: Thanks Peterm, that is what I am looking for! Any reference or practice I can refer to such that I can improve my SQL fundamentals? I am having trouble converting a set of requirements into SQL statements.

Comment: Practice practice practice. Read SO and try to understand/solve the questions. Sounds stupid, but really improves your skills.

Comment: @overst33r You're very welcome :) See updated answer for one more version of the query using analytical functions. Regarding your follow-up question there are plenty of books, courses out there. E.g. Oracle offers [Oracle Database 11g: SQL Fundamentals I - Self-Study Course](http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=609&p_org_id=1001&lang=US&get_params=dc:D55457,p_preview:N)

Comment: Hi Peterm, thanks for the update on the Analytical Function, it seems to have the best execution plan from my side.